# Feeding input to OpenCV DNN using cv2.dnn.blobFromImage()

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, python

I'm using OpenCV 4.3.0. I have a Tensorflow python implementation working and I'm trying to port it to OpenCV DNN in python.

**My Tensorflow Python implementation:**

```
     image = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
     image_resized = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
     image_normalized = np.add(image, -127) #normalization of the input
     feed_dict = {self.tf_pitch_input_vector : image_normalized}
     out = self._sess.run([self.cnn_pitch_output], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

At the beginning of my network there is a reshape layer,

```
    X = tf.reshape(data, shape=[-1, 64, 64, 3])
```

The image is fed through the feed_dict and reshaped as shown above in the first layer and the network proceeds.

This (Tensorflow python) works well.

**My OpenCV DNN implementation:**

```
    image = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("model.pb")
    resized = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64),  interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    input_blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(resized, 1, (64,64), -127, swapRB=False, crop=False)
    print("blob: shape {}".format(input_blob.shape))
    input_blob = input_blob.reshape(-1, 64, 64, 3) 
    print("blob: new shape {}".format(input_blob.shape))
    net.setInput(input_blob)
    out = net.forward()
```

The output of the shapes printed in above code looks like this,

```
    blob: shape (1, 3, 64, 64)
    blob: new shape (1, 64, 64, 3)
```

**Problem:** The problem is that the network output is not matching between Tensorflow Python and OpenCV DNN. Upon debugging, I see that the  the data fed in OpenCV DNN is different, when compared to Tensorflow python implementation. I'm sure there is something wrong either in blobFromImage() or after that.

Could someone let me know what is missing from my OPenCV DNN code?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The problem was with blobFromImage()

```
input_blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(resized, 1, (64,64), -127, swapRB=False, crop=False)
```

OpenCV Document says,

> mean -scalar with mean values which are subtracted from channels.
>   Values are intended to be in (mean-R, mean-G, mean-B) order if image
>   has BGR ordering and swapRB is true.

The mean value I used was wrong. My assumption was that passin "-127" would subtract 127. But actually blobFromImage subtracts 127 when we just pass 127.

Moreover, I was using just 127, we've to pass (127,127,127) for all 3 channels

RTFM :)